# How to find number of digits entered as integer input using if else and without using loop or len(str(variable))?

Tags: python, if-statement

Loop is mostly used for this solution
also we can do it using len function

how to do it using if else??

From loop it is solvable
From len () we can find the number of digits

How can the same be done using if else in python?

Comment: OK, but why do you want to do this? And what does `if`/`else` have to do with the length of a number?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use the base-10 logarithm.

```
from math import floor, log10
digits = 1+floor(log10(num))
```

I don't know where you want to use `if`/`then` here, since it's a number, not a true/false condition. I guess you can check to see if it has the right number of digits for your program, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it using list comprehension and without using len function:

```
input_str = input("Enter your string that contains digits: ")
number_of_digits = sum([1 for i in input_str if i.isdigit()])
print("there are {} digits in your input".format(number_of_digits))
```

Comment: this is a loop.